# $scope.$emit/$broadcast not working in Custom Directive Communication in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using HighCharts for representing **Stacked Bar Charts** as well as **Line Charts**.My Requirement is **onClick** of Stacked Bar Chart the Line Chart should be displayed corresponding to the portion clicked.I acheived it using **$broadcast** and **$on**. When i use **$emit** in **highchart.js** it is not working, but when i use **$broadcast** or **$scope.$parent.$broadcast** it works. Can someone please let me know why the upward flow of event is working and downward its not working. My both directive are reffering to same Controller.

In my case why **$scope.$emit** or **$scope.$broadcast** alone does'nt work?

`index.html`

```
    <div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
      <chart values='basicAreaChart' id="container" technology="3G" url="../json/HighCharts.json"></chart>

      <linechart values='basicLineChart' id="container2" technology="LTE" click='clicked'></linechart>
    </div>
```

`controller.js`

```
  angular.module('chartsExample', ['lineChart','highchart']).controller('MainCtrl',
    [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   } ]);
```

`highchart.js`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('highchart', []).directive('chart', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        chartData: "=values"
     },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    controller:function($scope,$element,$attrs,$http){
        $http.get($attrs.url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.chartData = data;
            console.log('technology='+$attrs.technology+' '+$scope.a);
        });
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs,$rootScope) {
         '+$attrs.type);

        $scope.$watch('chartData', function(value) {
            if (!value){
                //console.log('In return');
                return;
            }
          // Initiate the chartData.chart if it doesn't exist yet
           $scope.chartData.chart = $scope.chartData.chart ;
            $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo =$attrs.id

            $scope.chartData.chart.events = {
                click : function() {
                    console.log('Chart clicked '+$scope.isClicked+' '+$scope.a);
                    $scope.click="false";

                    $scope.$parent.$broadcast('HIGH_CHART_CLICKED', 'clicked');
         //This works but $scope.$emit or $scope.$broadcast does'nt work???

                }
            };
            $scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
        },true);
    }
};
});
```

`linechart.js`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('highchart', []).directive('chart', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        linechartData : "=values"
     },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    controller:function($scope,$element,$attrs,$http){
        $scope.$on('HIGH_CHART_CLICKED',function(e,data){
            console.log('Line chart Listening event');
            $http.get("../json/NewLineChart.json").success(function(data) {
                $scope.linechartData = data;
                console.log('this is from line chart');
            });
        });
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs,$rootScope) {
         '+$attrs.type);

        $scope.$watch('linechartData', function(value) {
            if (!value){
                //console.log('In return');
                return;
            }
          // Initiate the chartData.chart if it doesn't exist yet
           $scope.chartData.chart = $scope.chartData.chart ;
            $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo =$attrs.id
           }
            };
            $scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
        },true);
    }
};
});
```

Comment: What component is listening for the events?

Comment: @JoeEnzminger I didn't get your question.Please elaborate...to make it more clear..Highchart is sending an event to Line chart...

Comment: I don't see the component that is listening for the HIGH_CHART_CLICKED event....i.e $scope.$on('HIGH_CHART_CLICKED', function()......

Comment: I am extremely sorry...copy paste mistake. However, I have corrected it now.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger..Let me know if u need some more info...please clarify this point why this is happening...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.  You have two directives with the same name (chart).  This answer assumes the second is actually supposed to be linechart

chart and linechart are siblings.  So when you $broadcast an event from chart, it has no children, and no one hears it.

Likewise, if you $emit and event from chart, then it will get emitted to the parent scope (MainCtrl) and then on up the hierarchy to $rootScope.  It will never get to linechart

When you use $scope.$parent.$broadcast, then you are telling MainCtrl to broadcast the event to it's children, which happen to be chart and linechart so it works.

Long story short - angular is working as expected here.

Unlike browser events, angular events don't bubble down and then back up.  They are one way.

You could have MainCtrl listen for the event and then re-broadcast it:

In MainCtrl:

```
$scope.$on('HIGH_CHART....', function() {
    //rebroadcast to children
    var args = Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
    $scope.$broadcast('HIGH_CHART.....', args )
};
```

(or something similar.  You have to remove the first element from arguments and then call broadcast with the remaining arguments - outside the scope of the question).

Comment: Yes..now understanding is getting more clear and you are right that the second directive is lineChart....Thanks for the suggesting the other approach.